# F5 SDK - SSL Insecure request

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, f5

Is there a way to ignore SSL? I'm running Python 3.10.1

code:

```
from f5sdk.bigip import ManagementClient

device = ManagementClient('10.10.17.127', user='admin', password='F5passcode')
device.get_info()
```

Error seen:
f5sdk.utils.http_utils - WARNING: SSL Insecure request, recommend adding a valid certificate to the device

I tried using these as well as some other options:

```
urllib3.disable_warnings()
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Answer (score 2):

use management root...

from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot

mgmt = ManagementRoot("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxx")
pools = mgmt.tm.ltm.pools.get_collection()

also i think this F5 SDK seems not supported by F5.
check this..https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-common-python/blob/development/README.rst